# Scala Stream function evaluation

Tags: scala, lazy-evaluation, lazy-sequences

I got a following code:

```
trait Stream[+A] {
  def uncons: Option[(A, Stream[A])]
  def foldRight[B](z: => B)(f: (A, => B) => B): B = {
    uncons.map(t => {
      f(t._1, t._2.foldRight(z)(f))
    }).getOrElse(z)
  }
  def exists(p: A => Boolean) =
    foldRight(false)((x, acc) => acc || p(x))
  def forAll(p: A => Boolean) =
    foldRight(true)((x, acc) => p(x) && acc)
}

object Stream {
  def cons[A](h: => A, t: => Stream[A]): Stream[A] =
    new Stream[A] {
      lazy val uncons = Some((h, t))
    }
}
```

Then I create a Stream in a lazy manner and invoke `exists` method to check what stream elements were evaluated:

```
  println(Stream.cons({println("5"); 1}, Stream.cons({println("6"); 2}, Stream.cons({println("7"); 3}, Stream.cons({println("8"); 4}, Stream.empty)))).exists(_ == 1))
```

And what I see is:

```
5
6
7
8
true
```

So all the elements were evaluated in spite of only first one would be enough. I seem to understand why `exists` acts the way it does.

Then I run the following code:

```
println(Stream.cons({println("13"); 1}, Stream.cons({println("14"); 2}, Stream.cons({println("15"); 3}, Stream.cons({println("16"); 4}, Stream.empty)))).forAll(_ < 2))
```

and see the following:

```
13
14
false
```

So as far as `forAll` comes across a non-satisfying value it terminates the traversal.

But why `forAll` acts that way? What's the crucial difference between it and `exists`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two things to consider :

- the type of `acc`
- the order of `p(x)` in the boolean expression.

### Laziness

If you change the type of `acc` to `B`, you won't be able to fail-fast (or short-circuit) in either of your methods. You must know it since your code extensively uses laziness, but a variable of type `=> B` will get evaluated only when its value is required i.e. used in some expression. In this case, `acc` is the *future* of the result computed over the stream. This future will happen only if you try looking at it. Thus, to prevent the whole stream to be evaluated, you must prevent this future to be looked at.

### Short-circuiting in boolean expressions

This is where the order of `p(x)` matters. In the expression `a && b`, if `a` is `false` then we know the whole conjunction is also `false`, thus Scala won't try evaluating `b` because it's pointless.

### Combining the two

Now what happens if one of your operands is a lazy expression ? Well, if you have `lazyA || b`, Scala will read the expression from left to right and evaluate `lazyA`. In your case, `lazyA` represents the accumulation of the next element and the rest of the stream. Thus, `lazyA` expands to `a0 :: lazyA1`, which expands to `a0 :: a1 :: lazyA2`. You will therefore end up computing the whole stream just for computing the left part of your boolean binop.

Now, if you have `a && lazyB`, this expands to `a && (b0 :: b1 :: lazyB2)`. As you see here, as soon as `a` or `bi` is `false`, this will return without evaluating the right part of the statement. This is what happens in your `forAll`.

### How to fix it

The good news is that the fix is very easy : just swap the order of `p(x)` and `acc` : as soon as `p(x)` is `true`, the disjunction will return without evaluating `acc`, stopping the computation.

```
def exists(p: A => Boolean) = foldRight(false)((x, acc) => p(x) || acc)
```

Output :

```
5
true
```